# After device rotation, Painting position changes automatically in the custom view in android

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-custom-view

I have made a custom view for drawing on canvas. I am able to draw painting in the canvas but it's position changes after rotating the device. I can not afford to fix device orientation.

---

***In portrait mode***

[image: In portrait mode]

---

***In landscape mode***

[image: In landscape mode]

Comment: You'll have to save its size and position relative to the image on rotation, not relative to the screen. This can all be handled in life cycle callbacks of your custom view via parcaelable object.

Comment: Could you provide an example for the same?